# How to use ORMLite with the native Android driver?

Tags: android, jdbc, driver, android-sqlite, ormlite

I want use ORM with [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/docs/getting-started).

But, the example show how use JDBC driver, I want use SQLite native Android driver, how I can do with this ?  It's possible ?

Can you show me just an example how get the equivalent of

```
ConnectionSource connectionSource = new JdbcConnectionSource(databaseUrl);
```

With SQLite. All samples I've found use DatabaseHandler and I don't understood how to use with ORM.

Thanks for your help, will be usefull, sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read the [android section](http://ormlite.com/docs/android) of the docs, it's pretty easy.

Comment: Thank you, I had not see that part.

Comment: It was not pretty easy for a Android beginner :p
But it's done, and works well. Thx !

Answer (score 1):

Wow.  So the docs are covered with references to Android.  For example, if you had read the 1.4 section of the manual which I think you are quoting in your post, it says:

> NOTE: Android users should see the Android specific documentation later in the manual. See section [Using With Android](http://ormlite.com/docs/android). There are also complete code examples that can be used. See section [Example Code](http://ormlite.com/docs/android-examples).

If you do a google search for `ORMLite android` it takes you to this page entitled:

> [Lightweight Java ORM Supports Android and SQLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml)

If you did a search for `ormlite android examples` it would have shown you my [Android examples page](http://ormlite.com/android/examples/).